# How do you query upstream in a polymorphic association without raw SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

In my exercise app, users can "check" an exercise to complete it. If I know that checkable_type is 'Exercise' and have the checkable_id, how do I query the exercise name?

I'm not sure what to put in my controller to have a list of "completed exercises" and their names based on checkable_type and id.

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name 
    has_many :checks, :as => :checkable
end

class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :checkable, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :checkable, :checkable_id, :checkable_type
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :exercise_name
  has_many :checks, as: :checkable
end

class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :checkable, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessible :checkable_id, :checkable_type, :exercise_name
end
```

I realized I needed to call **.checkable** before calling the desired attributes in the exercise model.

```
<% @checks.each do |check| %>
  <%= check.checkable.exercise_name %>
  <%= check.checkable.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

This pulls the right exercise name and "completion time" (via created_at) from the exercise table.

Answer (score 0):

Would just joining the other model give you what you wanted?

```
completed_exercises = Exercise.joins(:checks)
```

That should produce an inner join, and AR already knows how to include the polymorphic association as part of the query.

Comment: Not quite - this pulls a list of all completed exercises but it won't show you when you completed and if you completed it multiple times. 

How can I do something like completed_exercises = Check.joins(:exercises)? So that I can pull the name of the exercise and created_at every time someone completes it?

Comment: In that case, I'd flip it around and start with Checks.  Something similar to swap.nil's answer.  Just make sure you include the exercises association so when you traverse check.exercise it doesn't trigger an N+1 query.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a scope `checkable_type`

```
scope :checkable_type, lambda { |class_name| where("checkable_type = ?", class_name) }
```

I guess you want the polymorphic records with type `'Exercise'` and that would be created only when exercises are completed or you can maintain it in a `completed_at` timestamp column for that matter.

Then you can pulls a list of all completed exercises

```
scope :completed, where('completed_at IS NOT NULL')

completed_exercises = Check.checkable_type('Exercise').completed
```

You may ignore the `completed` scope if that's not the case